# Android - taking actions after some time

Tags: android, time, delay, countdowntimer

I want to create an application where after clicking a button, user will see some information but not all at one moment, but in pieces after some time. For example, user clicks the button and it shows "GO STRAIGHT", then after 5 seconds it shows "TURN LEFT", then after next 3 seconds it shows "TURN RIGHT", then after next 2 seconds it shows "GO STRAIGHT" etc. For now i used CountDownTimer. I'm not sure this is a good idea but at least i got my first part of information and after 5 seconds i got second part. The problem is that i don't know how to make more of them and how to make information appear in different periods of time like 5 sec, 3 sec, 2 sec, etc. Should i create more CountDownTimers to achieve that or there is a better way? My simple code so far:

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {


TextView text1;

private static final String FORMAT = "%02d:%02d:%02d";

CountDownTimer CountDownTimer1;


int seconds , minutes;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    text1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);



}

public void onClick(View view)
{

    System.out.println("GO STRAIGHT");

     CountDownTimer1 = new CountDownTimer(5000, 1000) {

        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {


            text1.setText(""+String.format(FORMAT,
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millisUntilFinished),
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished) - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(
                            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millisUntilFinished)),
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millisUntilFinished) - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(
                            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished))));

        }

        public void onFinish() {
            text1.setText("done!");
            System.out.println("TURN LEFT");
        }
    }.start();
}


}
```

XML:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="34dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="58dp"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Action"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="89dp"
    android:onClick="onClick" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I also tried something like below, but it's not working so probably my thinking wasn't correct

```
public void onClick(View view)
{

    System.out.println("GO STRAIGHT");

     CountDownTimer1 = new CountDownTimer(50000, 1000) {

        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

            long time = millisUntilFinished;

            if(time == 40000)
            {
                System.out.println("TURN LEFT");
            }
            else if(time == 20000)
            {
                System.out.println("TURN RIGHT");
            }
            else if(time== 10000)
            {
                System.out.println("GO BACK");
            }


            text1.setText(""+String.format(FORMAT,
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millisUntilFinished),
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished) - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(
                            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millisUntilFinished)),
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millisUntilFinished) - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(
                            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished))));

        }

        public void onFinish() {
            text1.setText("done!");
            //System.out.println("TURN LEFT");
        }
    }.start();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a Handler and the postDelayed method to do some actions after some time. When a handler finishes its work you start another handler with another time interval and do other things when it finishes. Here are some examples: https://www.codota.com/android/methods/android.os.Handler/postDelayed

Comment: Thanks, it works better for my app than CountDownTimer